# Next_Batch_of_data_for_neuronal_net

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem reshaping my data for the next batch. I want them to be the type of an 1D-array.

This is the code:

```
def next_batch(X_t,y_t,num,batch_size):          
    return X_t[num-1].reshape(None,batch_size,1),y_t[num-1].reshape(None,1,1)
```

And this is the error that occurs:

```
File "LSTM-Classification.py", line 118, in next_batch
    return X_t[num-1].reshape(None,batch_size,1),y_t[num-1].reshape(None,1,1)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Try `X_t[num-1].reshape(-1,batch_size,1),y_t[num-1].reshape(-1,1,1)`

Comment: @Sergiu Groza: Is your issue resolved.

Comment: Hi @Sergiu Groza, kindly respond if the issue is already resolved. Thanks.